# Parse email and PDF data into Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need a Google Script to monitor my GSuite email, look for a specific sender, and then parse multiple data from an attached PDF file, into A Google Sheet.

Is this even possible with Google Script only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can with [GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app) + an Apps Script [time-based trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) + Google Drive to deal with the attachments and read it (follow [this tutorial](https://www.labnol.org/extract-text-from-pdf-220422) for example).